# Nativescript IoS Listview Dynamic Height Elements

Tags: ios, listview, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm building a nativescript angular app with a tabstrip and one of the pages has a search bar and results shown in a ListView.  The results returned can vary in length, so thus the height of each item can be different.  Everything displays fine when the search results come back, however if I go to another 'page' via the tab strip and return, iOS redraws all the listview items as the same height, causing some results to be cut off, and others to have a ton of white space.

If I start scrolling up and down in the listview and different items become visible, they start fixing themselves, thus causing the results to jerk down/up as heights change.  This is not an issue on Android.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<GridLayout rows="auto *" class="p-20">
    <GridLayout row="0" rows="*">
        <StackLayout row="0" class="input-field">
            <SearchBar #searchField hint="Search ..." class="input" (submit)="startSearch($event)" (clear)="startSearch($event)"></SearchBar>
        </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
    <GridLayout row="1">
        <ActivityIndicator [busy]="isSearchingKJ"></ActivityIndicator>
        <ListView *ngIf="kjResults?.length > 0" [items]="kjResults" (itemTap)="select($event)">
            <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label class="search" [text]="item.book + ' ' + item.chapter + ':' + item.verse"></Label>
                    <Label class="search-results" textWrap="true" (loaded)="displaySearchResult($event, item)"></Label>

                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
    </GridLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Here is the code generating the formatted text for each item:

```
 displaySearchResult(args, result) {
    const container = <Label>args.object;

    const formattedStringLabel = new FormattedString();
    for (const fragment of result.text) {
      const span = new Span();
      span.text = fragment.text;

      if (fragment.highlight) {
        span.fontWeight = '800';
      }

      formattedStringLabel.spans.push(span);
    }

    container.formattedText = formattedStringLabel;
  }
```

Example of iOS graphical glitches:
[image]

Comment: I guess it's because you are updating the label with formatted text after initial layout. If you don't use formatted text on loaded event, do you still see the same issue?

Comment: I moved everything to the template and it works, thanks!